# Radius of Convergence of $\sum n^{-1}z^{3n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

I want to find the Convergence Radius of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1}z^{3n}$ ($z\in\mathbb{C}$). Firstly, i set 
$b_k := \begin{cases}
    a_n=1/k, & \text{for } k=3n, \ n\in \mathbb{N}^* \\
    0, & \text{else}
  \end{cases}$

Now I have $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_kz^k$ and use Cauchy-Hadamard Criterion and get

$R=\frac{1}{\limsup |b_k|^{1/k}}=\frac{1}{\limsup \sqrt[3n]{|a_n|}}$

I know that $1/\limsup |a_k|^{1/n}=1$ and want to determine $R$ by the squeezing lemma.

This is where I am not quite sure anymore.

Can I make the estimate $\limsup |a_k|^{1/(3n)}\ge\limsup |a_k|^{1/n}=1$?

Because $|a_k|\le 1$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}^*$ we should have $1\ge \limsup |a_k|^{1/(3n)}$ too, right?

I concluded $R=1$ but I have my doubts, as I am a total newbe in series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's much simpler to do it like this:

- When $|z|<1$, the series converges, since$$\left|\frac{z^{3n}}n\right|=\frac{|z^3|^n}n\leqslant\left|z^3\right|^n$$and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|z^3|^n$ converges (since $\left|z^3\right|=|z|^3<1$). Therefore, the radius of convergence is *at least* $1$.
- Since the series diverges when $z=1$, the radius of convergens is *at most* $1$.

Therefore, the radius of convergence is $1$.